# Is it bad practice to render a React component through the return value of a regular javascript function?

Tags: reactjs

I'm not sure if I worded the question correctly but basically I have a bunch of React components but only one can be rendered at a time. I thought the cleanest way to do this was to have a map that maps the component name to the the component and a function that instantiates it (idk if I'm using the correct terminology). I have some of the code below.

```
import SampleWidget from "../Components/Widgets/SampleWidget";
import StockWidget from "../Components/Widgets/StockWidget/StockWidget";
import WeatherWidget from "../Components/Widgets/WeatherWidget";

export const widgetMap = {
  StockWidget: StockWidget,
  SampleWidget: SampleWidget,
  WeatherWidget: WeatherWidget,
};

export const getRenderableWidget = (name, props = {}) => {
  const Component = widgetMap[name];
  return <Component {...props} />;
};
```

Then in the parent component, I simply have to call this `getRenderableWidget` function and pass in a name to get the component I want to render. Is this bad practice? I wanted to avoid having all my components in this parent class and using a bunch of conditionals to determine what gets rendered.

Comment: Opinion questions aren't good for stackoverflow. React components return react elements, and so does your function, so it's fine. If you're dynamically looking up the component name, you might want to look into something like a [higher order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), alternately your `getRenderableWidget` could just return the `Component` class itself, i'm not sure what benefit the pattern you're using has.

Comment: 1. why not just export `getWidgetByName`? 2. don't you need the same conditions to determine the name of the component to render as you'd need to determine the class? Where's the advantage?

Comment: `getWidgetByName` is a lookup function since the `widgetMap` and `getRenderableWidget` live in different files in my project. I updated the code snippet to remove `getWidgetByName` since its not necessary for the example.

Comment: It's not necessarily bad practice, but I don't get why you need a function. Why not just export the object? `<widgetMap.StockWidget />` is perfectly fine. This format is actually used by some libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just turn the mapping function into a function component and use it directly.

```
import SampleWidget from "../Components/Widgets/SampleWidget";
import StockWidget from "../Components/Widgets/StockWidget/StockWidget";
import WeatherWidget from "../Components/Widgets/WeatherWidget";

export const widgetMap = {
  StockWidget: StockWidget,
  SampleWidget: SampleWidget,
  WeatherWidget: WeatherWidget,
};

export const Widget = ({ name, props }) => {
  const Component = widgetMap[name];
  return <Component {...props} />;
};

const Example = () => {
  return <div>
    <Widget name="SampleWidget" props={{ randomProp: 'test' }} />
  </div>;
}
```

A map is an acceptable way for you to generate a UI from a configurable schema. For example:

```
const schema = [
  {
    type: 'SampleWidget',
    props: {
      title: 'I am a sample widget!'
    }
  },
  {
    type: 'WeatherWidget',
    props: {
      title: 'I am a weather widget!'
    }
  }
];

const ExampleTwo = () => {
  return <div>
    {
      schema.map((s, i) => (
        <Widget key={i} name={s.type} props={s.props} />
      ))
    }
  </div>
}
```